# Замена пустых ячеек

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL. Нужно в определенных полях заменить пустые ячейки на одну заданную строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться UPDATE-запросом. Если под пустой ячейкой имеется в виду пустая строка, запрос может выглядеть следующим образом

```
UPDATE tbl SET fld = 'empty' WHERE fld = ''
```

Если пустая ячейка, это ячейка со значением `NULL` запрос может выглядеть следующим образом

```
UPDATE tbl SET fld = 'empty' WHERE fld IS NULL
```

Или можно объединить оба условия

```
UPDATE tbl SET fld = 'empty' WHERE fld = '' OR fld IS NULL
```